# Which is correct - 'did with the egg' or 'with the egg did'?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I'm writing a story, which takes place in a past. Can you tell me which option is correct?

When I was wondering what
1)did with the egg
2)with the egg did
someone pushed me.

I've chosen 1) but I'm not sure.

Comment: Both are completely nonsensical.  Where did you get this example?  And, *did someone pushed* me makes no sense no matter how you construct this sentence.

Comment: I don't understand my grammar book, I suppose. So maybe: 'I was wondering what to do with the egg' is correct?

Comment: Yes.  That would be MUCH better.

Comment: Paulina, it would be helpful if you would give some more context in your question.

Comment: I agree with Tristan. It's too vague the way the question is phrased.

Answer (score 1):

The question as worded is confusing.

If you mean the choice between

> *While I was wondering what **to do** with the egg, somebody pushed me.*

and

> *While I was wondering what with the egg **to do,** somebody pushed me.*

the first is more natural-sounding, whereas the second only works if you want to sound archaic or poetic.

Anyway, you may need to edit the question.